# Async WCF self hosted service

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await, servicehost

My objective is to implement an asynchronous self hosted WCF service which will run all requests in a single thread and make full use of the new C# 5 async features.

My server will be a Console app, in which I will setup a `SingleThreadSynchronizationContext`, as specified [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx), create and open a [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) and then run the `SynchronizationContext`, so all the WCF requests are handled in the same thread.

The problem is that, though the server was able to successfully handle all requests in the same thread, **async operations are blocking the execution and being serialized, instead of being interlaced.**

I prepared a simplified sample that reproduces the issue.

Here is my service contract (the same for server and client):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessageService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<bool> Post(String message);
}
```

The service implementation is the following (it is a bit simplified, but the final implementation may access databases or even call other services in asynchronous fashion):

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    public async Task<bool> Post(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[Thread {0} start] {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, message));

        await Task.Delay(5000);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[Thread {0} end] {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, message));

        return true;
    }
}
```

The service is hosted in a Console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var syncCtx = new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncCtx);

    using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MessageService)))
    {
        NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);

        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessageService), binding, address);
        serviceHost.Open();

        syncCtx.Run();

        serviceHost.Close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first thing I do is to setup a single threaded `SynchronizationContext`. Following, I create, configure and open a ServiceHost. According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx), as I've set the SynchronizationContext prior to its creation, the `ServiceHost` will capture it and all the client requests will be posted in the `SynchronizationContext`. In the sequence, I start the `SingleThreadSynchronizationContext` in the same thread.

I created a test client that will call the server in a fire-and-forget fashion.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(address);
    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
    IMessageService channel = ChannelFactory<IMessageService>.CreateChannel(binding, ep);

    using (channel as IDisposable)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string message = Console.ReadLine();
            channel.Post(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the example, I get the following results:

**Client**

[image]

**Server**

[image]

The messages are sent by the client with a minimal interval ( < 1s).
I expected the server would receive the first call and run it in the `SingleThreadSynchronizationContext` (queueing a new `WorkItem`. When the `await` keyword was reached, the `SynchronizationContext` would be once again captured, the continuation posted to it, and the method would return a Task at this point, freeing the `SynchronizationContext` to deal with the second request (at least start dealing with it).

As you can see by the Thread's id in the server log, the requests are being correctly posted in the `SynchronizationContext`. However, looking at the timestamps, we can see that the first request is being completed before the second is started, what totally defeats the purpose of having a async server.

**Why is that happening?**

**What is the correct way of implementing a WCF self hosted async server?**

I think the problem is with the SingleThreadSynchronizationContext, but I can't see how to implement it in any other manner.

I researched the subject, but I could not find more useful information on asynchronous WCF service hosting, especially using the Task based pattern.

**ADDITION**

Here is my implementation of the `SingleThreadedSinchronizationContext`. It is basically the same as the one in the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx):

```
public sealed class SingleThreadSynchronizationContext  
        : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<WorkItem> queue = new BlockingCollection<WorkItem>();

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        this.queue.Add(new WorkItem(d, state));
    }

    public void Complete() { 
        this.queue.CompleteAdding(); 
    }

    public void Run(CancellationToken cancellation = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        WorkItem workItem;

        while (this.queue.TryTake(out workItem, Timeout.Infinite, cancellation))
            workItem.Action(workItem.State);
    }
}

public class WorkItem
{
    public SendOrPostCallback Action { get; set; }
    public object State { get; set; }

    public WorkItem(SendOrPostCallback action, object state)
    {
        this.Action = action;
        this.State = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a blocking queue? I would use a ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: Well, it is the suggested implementation in the article, but I agree with it, because the SingleThreadSynchronizationContext has to wait for the next workitem to be inserted anyway. BlockingCollection.TryTake blocks until availability and in addition it has an elegant way to cancel the operation with a CancellationToken. Why would a ConcurrentQueue be preferable in this case? How would you wait for the next worktitem after finishing one's execution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to apply `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`.

This is where the terminology gets a bit confusing, because in this case it doesn't actually mean "multi-threaded" as the MSDN docs state. It means *concurrent*. By default (single concurrency), WCF will delay other requests until the original operation has *completed*, so you need to specify multiple concurrency to permit overlapping (concurrent) requests. Your `SynchronizationContext` will still guarantee only a single thread will process all the requests, so it's not *actually* multi-threading. It's single-threaded concurrency.

On a side note, you might want to consider a different `SynchronizationContext` that has cleaner shutdown semantics. The `SingleThreadSynchronizationContext` you are currently using will "clamp shut" if you call `Complete`; any `async` methods that are in an `await` are just never resumed.

I have an [`AsyncContext` type](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext) that has better support for clean shutdowns. If you install the Nito.AsyncEx NuGet package, you can use server code like this:

```
static SynchronizationContext syncCtx;
static ServiceHost serviceHost;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AsyncContext.Run(() =>
    {
        syncCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        syncCtx.OperationStarted();
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MessageService));
        Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;

        var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessageService), binding, address);
        serviceHost.Open();
    });
}

static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.BeginClose(_ => syncCtx.OperationCompleted(), null);
        serviceHost = null;
    }

    if (e.SpecialKey == ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlC)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This will translate Ctrl-C into a "soft" exit, meaning the application will continue running as long as there are client connections (or until the "close" times out). During the close, existing client connections can make new requests, but new client connections will be rejected.

Ctrl-Break is still a "hard" exit; there's nothing you can do to change that in a Console host.

Comment: ConcurrencyMode.Multiple was the key. Once I configured it in the service's behavior the application worked as expected. I'm going to take a look at Nito.AsyncEx, it looks promising. Thank you!